# Select option get value by text using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html select (dropdown) with many populated options. Also I have table with many Names with button next to it. I need that when you press the button next to any name then that name would be selected in select box(dropdown). Option value is id and option text is name.
Example:

---

```
!NamesList!v!   <- select box

John  !Button!
Tom   !Button!
Laura !Button!
```

---

I have tried to use:

```
var name = "John";
$("#cmbOperator option[value='" + name + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

but it doesn't work. If I change var name to id(which is value) then works. But how can I get option's value from its text?

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select option:contains(text)").attr('selected', true);
```

Here is the JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/u1c21mq6/1/

Answer (score 0):

**If your HTML is**:

```
<select id="cmbOperator">
    <option value="Jane">Jane</option>
    <option value="John">John</option>
</select>
```

**Use**:

`$("#cmbOperator option[value='" + name + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');`

- Selects based on the `value` attribute.

*or*

`$("#cmbOperator option:contains('" + name + "')").attr('selected', 'selected');`

- Selects based on the text content.

**If your HTML is**:

```
<select id="cmbOperator">
    <option>Jane</option>
    <option>John</option>
</select>
```

**Use**:

`$("#cmbOperator option:contains('" + name + "')").attr('selected', 'selected');`